# start program with another first window

Tags: c#, wpf

When I create new project - the window that was created by visual studio automatically will be the first window in program and it will be shown first.
How to set to another window in the project to be the first window to start?

For example - mainwindow.xml - first window. 
              auth.xml - new windows
I want to start it like this
auth->press button->mainwindow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [`StartupUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startupuri.aspx) in `App.xaml`.